# Locations PCLConfig.cmake and pcl-config.cmake files for PCL library

Tags: cmake, point-cloud-library

I installed PCL using the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcl-all
```

When I compiled my PCL program with the following lines in `CMakeLists.txt`

```
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

I have errors as

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
   By not providing "FindPCL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PCL", but
   CMake did not find one.

   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PCL" (requested
   version 1.3) with any of the following names:

     PCLConfig.cmake
     pcl-config.cmake

   Add the installation prefix of "PCL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "PCL_DIR"
   to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "PCL" provides a
   separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I can't locate PCLConfig.cmake and pcl-config.cmake in my system.

I did like

> locate PCLConfig.cmake

/home/ttt/.local/share/Trash/files/PCLConfig.cmake
/home/ttt/.local/share/Trash/files/DemoApplications-master/Calculus/tv_auto_on_off/voxel-sdk/libvoxelpcl/VoxelPCLConfig.cmake.in
/home/ttt/.local/share/Trash/files/config/VoxelPCLConfig.cmake.in
/home/ttt/.local/share/Trash/files/voxelsdk.2/config/VoxelPCLConfig.cmake.in
/home/ttt/.local/share/Trash/info/PCLConfig.cmake.trashinfo
/home/ttt/Softwares/voxelsdk/config/VoxelPCLConfig.cmake.in
/usr/lib/cmake/VoxelPCL/VoxelPCLConfig.cmake

Does it make sense?

I tried like

```
set(PCL_DIR "/home/ttt/.local/share/Trash/files/PCLConfig.cmake")
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

But still have the same error.
How to locate PCLConfig.cmake in my system?
Thanks

Comment: As written in error message, `PCL_DIR` should be a **directory**, contained required file. Files in trash are unlikely suited. It should be something like `<...>/cmake/PCL/PCLConfig.cmake` (like a file for `VoxelPCL` package, the last one in your output). In that case use `<...>/cmake/PCL` as value for `PCL_DIR` variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should specify the PCL dir for the CMake to find it.

In a terminal run :

```
$ locate PCLConfig.cmake
```

Then, add the found folder (without the filename) to your CMakeLists like the following :

```
set(PCL_DIR "/found/folder/")
#change X.x to whatever version yo installed
```

Sidenote : /usr/share/pcl-x.x is the usual path to your pcl folder.

Comment: Y my problem is I don't have /usr/share/pcl-X.x. I have /usr/include/pcl-X.x. And pcl library files in /usr/bin/libpcl*. How can I delete all those? I like to reinstall from source.

Comment: I uninstall and reinstall using (http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html) here. It doesn't create anything in /usr/share/...

Comment: Your suggestions are correct. But somehow, it worked for me by installing from source codes. s

Comment: @Vtik, what to do in WIndows 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I followed the steps mentioned on the website http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html, for Ubuntu 18.

You simply need to run
sudo apt install libpcl-dev

as bionic is not mentioned in the distributions (http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu/dists/)