# Trouble met when installing PCL on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: graphics, 3d, point-cloud-library

I have trouble in installing PCL 1.9 on my Ubuntu 18.04. Could anybody please help? Really thanks.

I already tried as many tutorials on the Internet. However they both won't work.

1. When trying to add `ppa` source and use `apt/apt-get` to install `libpcl-all`, it seems that the source doesn't work for `ubuntu18`.
2. When I was trying to build the `PCL` myself, on Ubuntu 18.04, it has lots of dependencies problems. Many tutorials say that using apt to install the dependencies, however some libraries are not available in apt.
3. There are some people suggesting to use `apt install libpcl-dev`. Although there is no errors in installation, when I tried to compile an example code, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using CMake toolchain for your build process? If so, are you sure you are linking PCL libraries? Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441189/locations-pclconfig-cmake-and-pcl-config-cmake-files-for-pcl-library).

Comment: Please provide everything you tried out and what the error messages were, e.g. you are saying that some libraries are not available via apt, which libraries though? 
I have no problems at all building PCL on Ubuntu 18.04 and also no problems installing `libpcl-dev` and using it in my project.

Comment: Please provide: commands used to add the ppa and install as well as the error messages. The same should be done for the other 2 points so other people can try to reproduce this issue. See the MCVE help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Using pcl-trunk might be your best choice.

```
git clone https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl pcl-trunk
cd pcl-trunk && mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```