# CmakeLists.txt file in Terminator Emulator

Tags: cmake, terminator

I am trying to use Visual Studio for my .cpp programs and Terminator to simulate in Ubuntu. I have a little knowledge of CmakeLists.txt but never used it before. I want to simulate the 3D point cloud in terminator but I'm stuck. How to set PCL_DIR and give it full path? The file is stored in -
home/shruti/Documents/LIDAR-SNFD-Detection-master/CMakeLists.txt.

Earlier I was getting this error -
[CMakeLists Directory Changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQuyX.png)

[Getting CmakeLists.txt Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb4Gs.png)

I'm new to Ubuntu and importing CMake files in Terminator. It would be good if I get some references on how to proceed. Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locations PCLConfig.cmake and pcl-config.cmake files for PCL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441189/locations-pclconfig-cmake-and-pcl-config-cmake-files-for-pcl-library)

Comment: Please, add the error messages into the question post as **text**, not as *links* to an *images*. This is a **requirement** of the Stack Overflow, see [ask].